# SSH replace string example

Tags: ssh

I need to replace multiple (150+) config.php files on live server that contain string

```
public_html/home2/cpaneluser
```

to

```
public_html/home/cpaneluser
```

can someone give me an example of SSH string replace please.

if you can give me an example of replacing ONE and replacing multiple please .
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`. This has not specific to `ssh`, which is just a way to login to a remote server.

```
sed -i.bak 's|public_html/home2/cpaneluser|public_html/home/cpaneluser|' file1 file2 ...
```

You say there are 150+ files. You can use `find` to find them and pass them to the command:

```
find <topdir> -name config.php -exec sed -i.bak 's|public_html/home2/cpaneluser|public_html/home/cpaneluser|' {} +
```

Comment: thank you much , do you mind updating the first one so I can test, the first file I want to test is /public_html/home/cpaneluser/test/config.php. thank you